# Full version of dua for beneficial knowledge

Tags: source-identification, dua

[Where can I find this dua from authentic sources on beneficial knowledge?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Te202CryeQ) The dua is at 25:05. [My Google search brought up only the first part of the dua](https://abuaminaelias.com/dailyhadithonline/2015/04/11/ask-allah-benefit-knowledge/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different wordings:

- > "Allahumma inni a'udhu bika min 'ilmin la yanfa'u, wa qalbin la yakhsha'u, wa du'a'in la yasma'u, wa nafsin la tashba'u.
  >   (O Allah, I seek refuge with You from
  >   knowledge that is of no benefit,
  >   a heart that is not humble,
  >   a supplication that is not heard
  >   and a soul that is not satisfied.)"
  >   Then he would say: 'Allahumma inni a'udhu bika min ha'ula'il-arba'
  >   (O Allah, I seek refuge with You from these four.)'"
  >   ([Sunan ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/nasai/50/43))
- > " 'Allahumma inni a'udhu bika min al-arba': min 'ilmin la yanfa'u, wa min qalbin la yakhsha'u, wa min nafsin la tashba'u, wa min du'a'in la yusma'u
  >   (O Allah, I seek refuge in You from four:
  >   From knowledge that is of no benefit,
  >   from a heart that is not humble,
  >   from a soul that is not satisfied
  >   and from a supplication that is not answered.)'"
  >   ([Sunan an-Nasa-i](https://sunnah.com/nasai/50/40), see also [here](https://sunnah.com/nasai/50/109), [here](https://sunnah.com/nasai/50/110) and in [Sunan ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1302570))
- > 'Allahumma, inni a'udhu bika min 'ilmin la yanfa'u, wa mindu'a'in la yusma'u, wa min qalbin la yakhsha'u, wa min nafsin la tashba'u
  >   [O Allah, I seek refuge with You
  >   from knowledge that is of no benefit,
  >   from a supplication that is not heard,
  >   from a heart that does not fear (You)
  >   and from a soul that is not satisfied].'"
  >   ([Sunan ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah/34/11) and [Sunan abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/8/133)
- > “O Allah, I seek refuge in You
  >   from a heart that does not humble itself,
  >   and from a supplication that is not heard,
  >   and from a soul that is never satisfied,
  >   and from knowledge that does not benefit,
  >   I seek refuge in You from these four
  >   (Allāhumma innī a'ūdhu bika min qalbin lā yakhsha'u, wa min du'ā’in lā yusma'u, wa min nafsin lā tashba'u, wa min 'ilmin lā yanfa'u, a'ūdhu bika min hā’ula’il-arba`).”
  >   ([Jami' at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/48/113))
- > 'Allahumma inni a'udhu bika min al-'ajzi wal-kasali, wal-bukhli, wal-jubni, wal-harami, wa 'adhabil-qabri. Allahumma at nafsi taqwaha, wa zakkaha anta khairu min zakkaha, anta waliyyuha wa mawlaha. Allahumma inni a'udhu bika min nafsin la tashba'u wa min qalbin la yakhsha'u wa min 'ilmin la yanfa'u wa du'a'in la yustajab
  >   (O Allah, I seek refuge in You
  >   from incapacity, laziness, miserliness, cowardice, old age, the torment of the grave. O Allah, make my soul obedient and purify it, for You are the best One to purify it, You are its Guardian and Lord. O Allah, I seek refuge in You
  >   from a soul that is not satisfied,
  >   a heart that is not humble,
  >   knowledge that is of no benefit
  >   and a supplication that is not answered.)'
  >   ([Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/48/99) and [Sunan an-Nasa-i](https://sunnah.com/nasai/50/111))

and as you see not all have the same order of the words and supplications.